# Single Spa: check for the user permissions before routing

Tags: javascript, routes, permissions, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am working on a single-spa application, which basically has a route mapping to the other MFE (micro frontend).

I do have access to the source of some of the MFE, but I do not own one MFE (let’s say “A”) before routing to which I should check the user permissions.

So, the task is: if the user has necessary permissions then route him to the MFE “A” otherwise route him to “access denied page”.

I have tried to find some solutions in the internet, and most of the answers are suggesting to perform the permissions check right on that MFE “A” (which is imposing for me).

What I found is that there is one event called “single-spa:before-routing-event”.

I am thinking about the following solution:

```
window.addEventListener(
  'single-spa:before-routing-event',
  ({ detail: { oldUrl, newUrl, cancelNavigation } }) => {
    if (
      new URL(oldUrl).pathname === “/MFE/a” && !userHasPermissions()
    ) {
      cancelNavigation();
      window.location.href = “http://localhost:8080/accessDeniedPage”
    }
  },
);
```

Would be very helpful if someone can review the solution and let me know whether it is a good one or are there any other approaches?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In order not to use the `window.location.href` I have imported 'single-spa' and using `navigateToUrl` function. But still I am wondering whether it is a good solution to do that through the mentioned event.

Comment: Did you made it?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('single-spa:app-change', evt => {
    const appNames = singleSpa.getAppNames();
    let app = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (!(appNames.includes(app))) {
        singleSpa.navigateToUrl('/pagenotfound');
    }
});
```